# Can we use the output of a method in a class as an attribute of that class

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to make a variable as an attribute in a class but at the same time this variable have to be calculated in a method inside this class . Here is my code:

```
class entrepot :
       def __init__(self,L_R,L_A,pos_porte,longueur,largeur):
          self.L_R=L_R
          self.L_A=L_A
          self.pos_porte=pos_porte
          self.longueur=longueur
          self.largeur=largeur

       def matrice_expedition(self):
          A=np.zeros((longueur,largeur-2))
          return (A)
```

am I allowed to add A as attribute? it sounds a stupid question but i'm still a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
# py2 / py3 compat: inherit from object for py2
# pep08 : class names should be CamelCase

class Entrepot(object):
   def __init__(self,L_R,L_A,pos_porte,longueur,largeur):
      self.L_R=L_R
      self.L_A=L_A
      self.pos_porte=pos_porte
      self.longueur=longueur
      self.largeur=largeur
      self.A = self.matrice_expedition()

   def matrice_expedition(self):
      # Python has no implict `this`, you need to
      # use `self.XXX` to access the current instance
      # attributes
      A = np.zeros((self.longueur,self.largeur-2))
      return A
```

Note that while technically legal, this code will not ensure that `self.A` stays consistant with `self.longeur` and `self.largeur` so if either of those attributes change later, you may have some issues.

If the warehouse (entrepot) size is not supposed to change after initialization, you can make `longueur` and `largeur` "protected" attributes by renaming them to `_longueur` and `_largeur` (note that this is only a naming convention - it won't prevent access to those attributes - but it's a very strong convention that tells users of your class that they should not mess with those attributes and are on their own if they do and break anything).

Also if you still want to provide public read access to `longueur` and `largeur` you can make them read-only properties:

```
class Entrepot(object):
   def __init__(self, L_R, L_A, pos_porte, longueur, largeur):
      self.L_R = L_R
      self.L_A = L_A
      self.pos_porte = pos_porte
      self._longueur=longueur
      self._largeur=largeur
      self.A = self.matrice_expedition()

   @property
   def longueur(self):
       return self._longueur

   @property
   def largeur(self):
       return self._largeur

   def matrice_expedition(self):
      # ....
```

Actually, you should only expose as "public" attributes (and methods) the attributes and methods that are supposed to be used by the client code (chances are you want to make "self.A" a protected attribute too)

Comment: very usefull explanation ! thank you ! just a question do i have to add the A to __int__ parameters?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean

Comment: :D i mean do i have to add A to parameters ? so i get : def __init__(self, L_R, L_A, pos_porte, longueur, largeur,A):

Comment: Why ? I'm not sure what this attribute is for (I assume some other method will fill it with informations), but it's obviously your class responsability to create it and none of the client code's concerns.

Comment: Glab I could help - and feel free to accept and / or upvote the answer then ;-)